# Intellij keymap - how to jump x lines up or down

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, goland

Is there any way to create a keymap for jumping x lines up or down in GoLand?
Just switched from sublime to Goland, and I really need this shortcut...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can only move one line up/down. You also have the option to use *Navigate | Line/Number* feature.

You can also create a custom macro for the IDE to use and customize exactly how you want it to behave. Go to *Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording* use arrow up/down as many times as you need, and then go to *Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording*. After you save it with a name, you can go to *Settings | Keymap*, search for the macro name and assign it a shortcut or even abbreviation to make it easy to find via the *Find Action*/*Search Everywhere* functionality.

Comment: Another thing - Do you happen to know if I can set the macro without animation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know this and a quick search on our issue tracker doesn't show any request for it. I suggest adding a request for it if you'd like. I would add it myself but I'm not sure I can capture the specific need/issue for this, sorry.